# JS: relation between "data-background-color" and .data("background-color")

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm currently working through the [Working with Javascript in Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html). The relation between this line

```
backgroundColor = $(this).data("background-color")
```

and that one is puzzling me:

```
<a href="#" data-background-color="#990000">Paint it red</a>
```

As I understand, it sets the bg color of "this". From where does the function get the value for data("background-color")?

My guess is that the "data-" before "background-color" allows the function to access the value in the HTML?

I'd be thankful for explaining this relation and pointing me to further information.

Here is the full JS/coffeescipt code:

```
paintIt = (element, backgroundColor, textColor) ->
  element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  if textColor?
    element.style.color = textColor

$ ->
  $("a[data-background-color]").click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()

  backgroundColor = $(this).data("background-color")
  textColor = $(this).data("text-color")
  paintIt(this, backgroundColor, textColor)
```

The full HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-background-color="#990000">Paint it red</a>
<a href="#" data-background-color="#009900" data-text-color="#FFFFFF">Paint it green</a>
<a href="#" data-background-color="#000099" data-text-color="#FFFFFF">Paint it blue</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are essentially right. The jQuery [.data(key)](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method in your use case allows to retrieve the corresponding `data-` attribute of the dom element to which it applies.

So for instance, `$(this).data('background-color')` will retrieve the `data-background-color` attribute of the dom element referecend by `this`.

So your second method does the following: whenever an anchor (`a`) element that has a `data-background-color` attribute is clicked, its background and font colors are respectively set to the value of its `data-background-color` and `data-text-color` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 custom data attribute you use in your document and still have a valid markup.Browser understand data- as a custom attribute .
And custom data attribute stores the value temporarily .And you called it.this reffered to object a when You
 click on a it will set the color accordingly .